# Dynamic Field names and Setting an autofill ID possible

Tags: forms, dynamic, autofill

I currently have a form for naming alt text on uploaded images, this number is unlimited so fields are named alt-1 TO alt-XXXXXXX pulling in the ID if the image from the database.

I used to upload one image at a time and add the alt text, this would allow browser autofill to key on the field name "alt".  Of course the fields names are all different now making autofill not work.  I trield setting autofill="altext" in the input but that did not work, also tried setting all the fields with the same ID..

My only thought is to possible try to use my dynamic value for the ID, then use javascript on submit to rename the field names the the dynamic value but I hope there is a more sound solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those who search for this insane "feature here is a shor script that I call on the form line with onsubmit = "replaceAlt()"

I named the ID in the Input fields what I want the names to be, then used "alt" for all the input fields that I want to be altered.

```
<script>
function replaceAlt() {
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var arrayOfInputNames = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var n = x[i].name;
    if (n == "alt"){
      x[i].name = x[i].id;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```